# Loading a Pandas DataFrame with data from a PyMongo cursor/iterator is too slow

Tags: python, mongodb, pandas, dataframe, pymongo

I have to extract 230000 documents form a mongo database located in another country and load them into a DataFrame.

The `cursor = mydb.mycollection.find(filter, {"projection 1": 1, "projection 2": 1, "projection 3": 1, ... , "projection 18": 1}, batch_size=25000)` finds the data instantly, but transferring it to a dataframe using `df = DataFrame(list(cursor))` takes 24 seconds, which is too long.

I have tried to turn the iterator to multiple small dataframes and to concatenate them, but the result is the same (24 seconds):

```
    def iterator2dataframes(iterator, chunk_size: int):
      """Turn an iterator into multiple small pandas.DataFrame
      This is a balance between memory and efficiency"""
      records = []
      frames = []
      for i, record in enumerate(iterator):
          records.append(record)
          if i % chunk_size == chunk_size - 1:
              frames.append(pd.DataFrame(records))
              records = []
      if records:
          frames.append(pd.DataFrame(records))
      return pd.concat(frames)
    df = iterator2dataframes(cursor, 25000)
```

How can I speed this up? Especially since at one point I will have to load a DataFrame using 30-40 million Mongo documents in as short of a time as possible.

Is there a way to use a bulk dump to the dataframe?